# Linear regression value errors with Scipy

Tags: python, linear-regression, scipy.stats, standard-error

I have two data arrays, xdata of shape (40,) and ydata of shape (40, 721, 1440) (time, lat, lon). My final goal is to compute the regression slope between these two datasets and obtain the errors from the slope to show the error distribution, where x is average sea surface temperatures for 40 years and y is an atmospheric variable. I have done this using one method where I calculated the covariance and then took the square root of this array, which if I understand correct, leaves me with the standard error. To verify this approach, I found the scipy.stat.linregress function and wanted to use this as it returns the standard error while calculating the slope. Although, I am running into errors when coding this.

To get my arrays the same size:

```
Y = ydata.stack(allpoints = ['lat','lon'])
X = xdata.values[:, None] * np.ones(Y.shape)
```

Here, I have stacked my ydata into a 2D array rather than a 3D array, leaving with me with the dimensions of (40, 1038240). Then I create a temporary array to of the xdata, with an extra dimensions filled with ones to get the two arrays of the same shape. After this I pass it through the function:

```
test = stats.linregress(X,Y)
```

And I am left with a value error saying:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

UPDATE:

I was able to get the package I was interested in using working:

```
from scipy import stats
ny = 721
nx = 1440
n = nx * ny
cape_2d = cape_ds.values.reshape(40,n)
reg_results = np.empty((5,n))

for i in range(n):
    reg_results[:,i] = stats.linregress(b,cape_2d[:,i])


slope, intercept, r_val, p_val, std_err = reg_results.reshape((5,ny,nx))
err_shape = std_err.reshape(721*1440)

plt.plot(err_shape)
```

[image: Histogram of Standard Error]

[image: Regression Slope]

At this point, I think I may have the correct answer, but Im worried that my standard errors are too high...Im not sure what to for it to look like, I was just hoping to get a normal distribution.

Comment: Won't this regression produce the same value for every Y point at the same time-step? Seems like you could simplify the problem by taking the mean of Y across all latitude and longitudes, giving you a Y array of shape (40,).

Comment: Im not sure? I dont think so...I have successfully completed the regression part of this problem using another method, but I am now just trying to see my error distribution and my initial method did not calculate this directly so I tried to take the sqrt(cov) and to check this, I wanted to use this package/function for the standard error.

Comment: If you have an already-working way of doing this regression, you could run your linear regression, get Y_pred, and calculate `Y - Y_pred`. You could then flatten that, and plot it using a histogram. That would show you the magnitude of the residuals, as well as what distribution it has.

Comment: I would get Y_pred by y_pred = slope*X + intercept, right? And then just subtract from the Y data array I input into the regression function? I have done this but the histogram does not seem like what I would expect it to be...

Comment: Most linear regression packages give some .fit() or .predict() method for getting predictions from X values. Are you using a linear regression package, or did you write your own code for fitting it?

Comment: I found one that is able to calculate the covariance, correlation, slope and intercept. I was also able to get stats.linregress() to work but I am confused on the plot that the standard error is producing. I imagine the error magnitude is given on the x axis and on the y axis is the sum of the number of data points?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what package you're using to fit this regression, how you're fitting this linear regression, and how you're producing the plot you're referencing? Ideally by adding code for how you're doing this to the question.

Comment: In the line `plt.plot(std_err)`, this is making a line graph of standard error, where Y is the magnitude of the standard error, and the X axis is the index within the array. You probably want `plt.hist(std_err)`.

Comment: @NickODell Great, I think I got it! Its just not what I wanted to find!! Haha but that's research...Thank you so much for your time and patience with me! I really really really appreciated it!